# Use of XSSFWorkbook Sheet interface results in Java Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, excel, xssf

I am trying to use the XSSFWorkbook from org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel to read an Excel file. For some reason I am getting a Null Pointer exception when I try to pull data from one of the Sheet methods. I am very new to Java programming, and it may be something very fundamental.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
public class ReadFile {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    File f = new File("C:/Users/munish/Documents/Training/Selenium/sample.xlsx");
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(f);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    int rowsCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    System.out.println("Total number of rows: " + (rowsCount + 1));
    for (int i = 0; i <= rowsCount; i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        int colCounts = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        System.out.println("Total number of Cols: " + colCounts);
        for (int j = 0; j < colCounts; j++) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
            System.out.println("[" + i + "," + j + "]=" + cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the NPE?  Highlighting the line on which it throws would help too.

Comment: The Null Pointer Exception is occurring at the 'int rowsCount...' line

Comment: So that means `workbook.getSheetAt(0)` is returning null.  Any idea why?

Comment: I verified the file location and the file itself - the first tab (index 0) has all the data. So I don't understand why i'm getting the error.

Answer (score -1):

Your `for` loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
```

not

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rowsCount; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't think there is a spelling issue here; in any case, the null pointer exception is thrown 2 lines above this, so we are not even getting to this line.

Comment: Where do you see `rowsCoutn` in the question above?

Comment: That was a typo on my part.  My answer was meant to be about < vs <=